# quadratic sequence Perfect Square values

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

For quadratic sequence

$$f(n) = n^2 + n +  2534125$$

I need to find a few values of $n$ where $f(n)$ becomes a perfect square, I followed several examples but
couldn't find a solution. By trial and error, $n=99,1096$ are the first two values, and I am stuck. This is what I have done so far:

Completing the square :

$$f(n) =  (n +1591)^2  -3181n + 2844  = X^2$$

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if $n^2 + n + 2534125 = w^2$ then $4 n^2 + 4n + 10136500  = 4 w^2,$   or  $4 n^2 + 4n + 10136500  = v^2$  by taking $v = 2w.$  NOW complete the square;     When is $4 n^2 + 4n + ?$ a square

Comment: thank you. $(2n+2)^2 = 4n^2 +  8n + 4$  and does not help us here. Good start, try other possibilities $ (2n + ??)^2 $

Comment: alright, errands to do,  for a fixed number $c,$   $(2n+c)^2 = 4n^2 + 4cn + c^2;$   to get  the $4n^2 + 4n $  part, what choice would be best for $c?$

Comment: Write $c$ for $2534125$. $u^2=n^2+n+c$; $4u^2=4n^2+4n+4c=(4n^2+4n+1)+(4c-1)=(2n+1)^2+(4c-1)=v^2+(4c-1)$ where $v=2n+1$; $4u^2-v^2=4c-1$. Now for every way to factor $4c-1=rs$ we can take $2u=(r+s)/2$, $v=(r-s)/2$. The end.

Comment: $ 4 n^2 + 4n + 10136500  = 4n^2 + 4n + 1 + 10136499  = (2n+1)^2 + 10136499 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$m^2=n^2+n+2534125$$where $m\in\mathbb{N}$.$$(2m)^2=4m^2=4n^2+4n+10136500=(2n+1)^2+10136499$$
$$(2m+2n+1)(2m-2n-1)=(2m)^2-(2n+1)^2=10136499$$
$$m,n\in\mathbb{N}\Rightarrow2m+2n+1,2m-2n-1\in\mathbb{N}$$
$$2m+2n+1>2m-2n-1$$
$$(2m+2n+1,2m-2n-1)=(10136499,1),(3378833,3),(10167,997),(3389,2991)$$
$$(m,n)=(2534125,2534124),(844709,844707),(2791,2292),(1595,99)$$
$\therefore n$ can be $2534124$, $844707$, $2992$ or $99$.

Comment: OP said $1096$ was an answer. Is that wrong?

Comment: It does seem wrong, using a calculator.